# Save terminal output to a txt file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, printing, c++

For the delivery I've been advised to print the full output of my program to a txt file. Also I need to print the execution time using the command "time" that I have implemented in my execution script.

```
#!/bin/bash
time ./blur-effect 4k.png 4k_out16.png 16 15 &>> Output.txt
```

The problem I'm having is that the program output is going correctly to the txt file, but the execution time is being showed in the terminal but it must be printed also in the txt file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should work the way you want if you wrap the command in a *command group* or subshell:

```
{ time ./blur-effect 4k.png 4k_out16.png 16 15 ; } &>> Output.txt
```

or

```
(time ./blur-effect 4k.png 4k_out16.png 16 15) &>> Output.txt
```

See [Write output of `time` in a file, why are parentheses needed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256324/65304)

Comment: In https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/61798, "`&>`, `>&`, `>>&` and `&>>`" are described as "non-standard". So is there a standard way?

Answer (score 7):

In Bash, `time` is a [shell key word for pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) which interprets stream redirection to occur only on the timed command (pipeline); it also happens to be a common *nix utility program:

```
$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
```

If you want to redirect streams to/from `time` you can either use [command groups or sub-shells as explained in steeldriver’s answer](/a/1139288/175814) or call the [`time(1)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/time.1.html) utility program explicitly:

```
/usr/bin/time COMMAND... &> LOGFILE
```

or if you’re unsure about the full path of `time`

```
time="$(which time)"
"$time" COMMAND... &> LOGFILE
```

---

P.S.: You can save the output of the `time(1)` command to a file that is not connected to the command’s standard error output (which is the default) in case you want to preserve the timed program’s standard error output unaltered with the `-o` option. `-a` makes `time` append to that file instead of overwriting it.

```
/usr/bin/time [-a] -o time.log COMMAND... >command-stdout.log 2>command-stderr.log
```

To achieve the same effect with the `time` shell key word (as usual, use `>>` instead of `>` redirection to append instead of overwrite):

```
{ time COMMAND... >command-stdout.log 2>command-stderr.log; } 2>time.log
```

Or to save the time log but leave the timed program’s standard error output as it is:

```
{ time COMMAND... 2>&3; } 3>&2 2>time.log
```